# AWS S3 NotResource/Deny and Resource/Condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I'm attempting to use a NotResource/Deny as follows

```
  "Action": [
    "s3:*"
  ],
  "NotResource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/file.txt",
  ],
  "Effect": "Deny"
},
```

with a StringLike Condition for s3:ListObjectVersions as follows

```
 {
      "Action": [
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "anotherfile.txt"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

The NotResource/Deny blocks the Resource with Condition. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Can you be clear as to what you want to make it work..

Comment: I want to lock down S3 so that all s3 actions are denied and only allow  List* (ListObjectVersions) for the condition shown.

Comment: S3 is locked down by default.  If there are actions allowed, you may want to investigate how that has happened.   Note also that IAM policy interpretation is never ambiguous -- a matching `Deny` always prevails over a matching `Allow`.

Answer (score 2):

The priority accessing policy as below:

```
Explicit Deny > Explicit Allow > Default Deny All
```

Map with your setting:

```
Deny "NotResource" > Allow "StringLike" > Default Deny All
```

You can use below policy to allow all others which is not `arn:aws:s3:::bucket/file.txt`

```
{
      "Action": [
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:prefix": "file.txt"
        }
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```